# State not getting set inside fetch inside useeffect

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to set the state inside a fetch callback for response, I have used the fetch inside the useEffect hook which has an empty array for dependency so it should execute only once,

```
"use strict";
var { useState , useEffect } = React;

// import { getPlatforms } from '../services/searchrule.service.js';

function SearchRule(){
    var [state,setState] = useState({
        platform: "",
        taskName: "",
        searchTerm : "",
        entity: "",
        platforms: [],
        entities: []
    });

    useEffect(function(){

        getPlatforms().then(function(res){
            return res.json();
        })
        .then(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            setState({
                ...state,
                platforms: data
            });
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });

        getEntities().then(function(res){
            return res.json();
         })
        .then(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            setState({
                ...state,
                entities:  data
            });
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
    },[]);




    useEffect(function(){

        const {entity, entities} = state;

        const selectedEntity = entities.filter(function(item) { return item.name === entity && entity !== "";});
        console.log(selectedEntity);


    },[state.entity]);

    function handleChange(e){
        setState({
            ...state,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
    }



    return (
            <div className="search-rule-body">
                <div className="inputs-container">
                    <h5>Search Rule</h5>
                    <label>Platform</label>
                    <select onChange={handleChange} value={state.platform} name="platform" defaultValue={undefined}>
                        {/*{*/}
                        {/*    state.platforms.map(platform => (*/}
                        {/*        <option key={platform}>*/}
                        {/*            {platform}*/}
                        {/*        </option>*/}
                        {/*    ))*/}
                        {/*}*/}
                    </select>
                    <label>Task Name</label>
                    <textarea placeholder="Task Name" value={state.taskName} onChange={handleChange} name="taskName"></textarea>
                    <label>Search Term</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search Term" name="searchTerm" onChange={handleChange}></input>
                    <label>For Entity</label>
                    <select onChange={handleChange} name="entity" defaultValue={undefined}>

                        {/*{*/}
                        {/*    state.entities.map(entity => (*/}
                        {/*        <option key={entity.name}>*/}
                        {/*            {entity.name}*/}
                        {/*        </option>*/}
                        {/*    ))*/}
                        {/*}*/}
                    </select>
                    <button style={{marginLeft: "75%", marginTop: "30px"}}>Test</button>
                    <h5>Fields</h5>
               </div>
                <div className="response-viewer-container">
                    <div>
                        <label>Search terms</label>
                        <p>search</p>

                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <textarea></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="search-values-container">

                </div>
            </div>
        )
}
```

When I check the console logs both the values are getting logged but when I check the component inside the react dev tool only the entities are getting set but not the platforms array.

Platforms: `["Google Custom Search",...]`
Entities: `[{ code: "contact" createdBy: 1 createdOn: "2021-02-02T05:22:29.838+0000" id: 1 isActive: true name: "Contact" updatedBy: null updatedOn: "2021-02-02T05:22:29.838+0000" },...]`

Comment: could you show a part of you data , I think the result isn't an array ! may be an object

Comment: I just did check it out

Comment: But whatever the type would be it should at least get set to the value in state.

Comment: I added a useeffect with state as the dependency and added a console.log(state) inside it, It seems that the platforms are getting set but after the entities are set the platforms become undefined again, But the spread operator should avoid that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write your setState passing a callback as:

plataform:

```
        setState(state => ({
            ...state,
            platforms: data
        }))
```

entities:

```
        setState(state => ({
            ...state,
            entities:  data
        }))
```

this way you ensure pass the current state on each state update. your error is likely due to closure, where your second setState is using the same initial state where plataform is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Don't write the function inside the `useEffect` hook.

Separate them:

```
`function getData(){
        getPlatforms().then(function(res){
            return res.json();
        })
        .then(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            setState({
                ...state,
                platforms: data
            });
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });

        getEntities().then(function(res){
            return res.json();
         })
        .then(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            setState({
                ...state,
                entities:  data
            });
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
`
```

And:

```
`useEffect(() => {
    getData()
}, []} `
```

<- as you know, using an empty array it means that the `useEffect` it takes places just when the page renders the first time

Comment: I did just that & now the platforms array is populated but not the entities

Comment: Try to separate them and call both in useEffect, it might help